# Use one activity : inflate a new layout for each view or use fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am working on android application and some team members suggested using one activity and one parent layout for the whole application and each time we need a new screen we just inflate a new layout in the parent layout and destroy the old one.
I on the other hand think that using fragments would be the way to go.

Do you think one way is better than the other? 
I would be grateful if you can think of solid arguments to support your claim.

Thank you

UPDATE:

We are using MVC in our application. They want to create a new class for the view while i opted for using the fragment as my view. As it stands now the application has one activity and one layout. To change the view we are calling the same layout,removing its child views and inflating the new view .I dont see how that would be better then just using the fragments as views

Comment: go for one activity with fragments.

Comment: You should use activity as well as fragment as per your screen layout design. The approach you taking singleActivity all other fragment is not good approach in my opinion.

Comment: please see my updated answer

Comment: Actually there are some people who advocate not using Fragments because the lifecycles are too complicated. You can google the article by Square about Fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most Android developers will tell you to use one or more Activities or Fragments. But why?

Basically, because one Activity which is responsible for each and every View in your app would be something like a "god object". This is considered an antipattern, I suppose because it may fast become a maintenance nightmare.

The Android pattern of one Activity and several Fragments on the other hand is following the Single Responsibility Principle, so your code is easier to maintain. All the more so because Android-specific  things like saving state on configuration change are much easier to implement if you are able to use the built-in methods.

Comment: @HAOUAS Khaled -Hope my answer is a little bit helpful. The way your question keeps gathering downvotes, you may want to delete it. As far as I'm concerned, you're welcome to do so. Happy coding!